# What's about the relationship between mathematics and physics via Noether theorem?

Tags: soft-question, physics, mathematical-physics, euler-lagrange-equation

I am interesting in a brief introduction for mathematicians about what is the [Noether Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem), and what's about the relationship between and mathematics and physics, concerning this theorem, if there were examples being this theorem the interface between both territories.

> **Question.** Are there some relationship or potentially/hypothetical relationships between mathematics and physics linked by the Noether Theorem? Please can you please explain it with your reasoning and mathematics, if it is possible. What were such examples (if from your interpretation there were such examples)? **Thanks in advance.**

The question isn't mine, is (myself) an interpretation of a question that was asked in a video.

Comment: I am asking by examples that were first in the literature in mathematics, and after were *discovered/interpreted* by phisicians.

Comment: Thanks for your edit @anomaly.

Comment: From a physical perspective, I'd recommend reading the exceptionally elegant introduction in the first chapter of Landau and Lifshitz Mechanics (found [here](https://ia800307.us.archive.org/11/items/Mechanics_541/LandauLifshitz-Mechanics.pdf)).

Comment: Very thanks much @JacobAustin Since I believe that it is interesting I am asking about it, to obtain a nice (and with easy words) answers from the users of this site. Very thanks much for your reference.

Comment: A little detail : phisicians $\rightarrow$ physicists (a physician treats illnesses, not a physicist)

Comment: Uff ! my english is terrible, I think it was one of the causes of Brexit @JeanMarie